# iOS device log crashed EXC_CRASH 0x0000000000000000

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have only a little knowledge on how to read the crash reason in device logs. Please give me some clue on where should I start to look at in my app. It crashed the minute I clicked on a button when I open the app. I only got this error when I unplugged the device. I cannot reproduce the device if I try to build with my phone via Xcode.

Thank you.

```
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.5 (11B601)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  1

Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a45bb66 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3003ec4a -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] +     178

2   UIKit                           0x32b157a4 -[NSString(UIStringDrawingLegacy) _legacy_drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:truncationRect:] + 456

3   UIKit                           0x32b155c8 -[NSString(UIStringDrawingLegacy) _legacy_drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:lineSpacing:includeEmoji:] + 72
4   UIKit                           0x32b15512 -[NSString(UIStringDrawingLegacy) _legacy_drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:] + 70
5   UIKit                           0x32b14f9e -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawInRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:alignment:] + 54
6   ST iPhone Standalone AppStore   0x001fc4a4 -[ArticleTableViewCell_CG drawContentView:] (ArticleTableViewCell_CG.m:178)
7   ST iPhone Standalone AppStore   0x001f9a7c -[ABTableViewCellView drawRect:] (ABTableViewCell.m:43)
8   UIKit                           0x32907dd4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 368
9   QuartzCore                      0x3253da74 -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 96
10  QuartzCore                      0x32527240 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 1856
11  QuartzCore                      0x326012e8 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 48

12  QuartzCore                      0x32526af0 x_blame_allocations + 80
13  QuartzCore                      0x325267a2 CA::Layer::display_() + 1114
14  QuartzCore                      0x3250a364 CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 204
15  QuartzCore                      0x32509ffc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 20
16  QuartzCore                      0x32509a08 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 224
17  QuartzCore                      0x3250981a CA::Transaction::commit() + 310
18  QuartzCore                      0x32503548     CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 52
19  CoreFoundation                  0x300cef66     __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
20  CoreFoundation                  0x300cc8f2 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 282
21  CoreFoundation                  0x300ccc3e __CFRunLoopRun + 734
22  CoreFoundation                  0x3003746c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
23  CoreFoundation                  0x3003724e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
24  GraphicsServices                0x34d712e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
25  UIKit                           0x328ec840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
26  ST iPhone Standalone AppStore   0x000597cc main (main.m:14)
27  ST iPhone Standalone AppStore   0x00059764 start + 36

Thread 1 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a9fd838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a94c0d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a94661e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34
```

Comment: Line 178 of your code is trying to set an object in an NSDictionary and failing - probable because it is nil.

Comment: Also `setObject:forKey:`requires a `NSMutableDictionary`. Maybe you add some relevant code so helping is easier.

Comment: From the stack trace it's pretty clear that `setObject:forKey:` is not called by code the OP wrote. And `__NSDictionaryM` is a mutable dictionary. That's not the problem. ;-)